# vuejs2 listening for if the user pressed the @ key

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I know i can listen for key events in vue.js and add modifiers to those events like **keyup.enter**. But i can't seem to find a modifier for the @ key, something like **keyup.AT or keyup.at** etc.

Is there a way to watch for this key event in vue.js2?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@keyup.shift.50` to capture that both the <kbd>⇧</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd> keys were pressed on non-mobile QWERTY and DVORAK keyboards. I'm not sure about foreign keyboards.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    log:[]
  },
  methods:{
    onAt(evt){
      this.log.push("@ pressed")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" @keyup.shift.50="onAt">
  <hr>
  <div v-for="msg in log">{{msg}}</div>
</div>
```

This solution, however, will not trigger for mobile keypads where the <kbd>@</kbd> key has a dedicated button. I don't think there is a way to handle that using an event modifier in Vue, so you would have to resort to handling the keyup event and examining the event object.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    log:[]
  },
  methods:{
    onKeyUp(evt){
      if ("@" === evt.key)
        this.log.push("@ pressed")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" @keyup="onKeyUp">
  <hr>
  <div v-for="msg in log">{{msg}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Bert, thanks for your answer!! I don't have knowledge of the setup of all different types of keyboards, but is this going to work for all setups/MAC/Window etc?

Comment: @YeasirArafatMajumder it's based off the Javascript KeyboardEvent object,  but I really don't know if there is some keyboard that would use a different key combo for @. As far as I know the only way to type an @ is with shift and the 2 key. This is a case where I could definitely be wrong though. For standard QUERTY, yes, it will work. Also for DVORAK. For foreign keyboards your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: Mobile devices have a dedicated key for the @ character. Do you have any idea of what should the approach be for those?

Comment: @YeasirArafatMajumder Good point. In the case of a mobile keyboard, I don't think you can use modifiers to detect @. You have to resort to handling the event and examining the event object. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: On German mac keyboards, @ is <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. On German Windows keyboards, @ is ALTGR-Q.